# Does the rejection of a suggested edit with the reason "Vandalism" flag the post in any way?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, vandalism

In the process of rejecting a suggested edit, a reason must now be given (`copied content, invalid edit, radical change, too minor, or vandalism`).

If we select vandalism for the reason, does this mark the post in any way to be checked by a mod?  Should this be something that is reported?

The particular case that I'm thinking of was a [tag wiki edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/120499) so, it can't really be flagged.  Whether that example is actually vandalism is perhaps up for debate, as I suppose it could have been a misunderstanding, but I ask this for the generic case where there is no question of the intent of the editor.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, there is no automatic flagging of any sort triggered by using the vandalism edit rejection reason. For otherwise isolated incidents, it isn't entirely necessary to alert the moderators, either. It's a bit like spam flags - we get alerted if the spam flags are live and so the post is still around, but once you've blasted the post to smithereens with enough spam flags, we no longer get alerted. This is because when the post has been obliterated, the problem is solved. Same with rejection - if the rejection goes through, the vandalizing edit is eradicated and so the spam is already handled.

Now, if a user was *consistently* providing a series of vandalizing edits, *that* would be a fine time to flag for moderator attention - we may have to step in and take stronger measures. If they're editing a normal post, you should flag it directly - otherwise, flag down a post of theirs or a post of your own and simply include relevant links to at least one such suggested edit in your custom reason.

Comment: I guess it would be tough to know if a user was consistently attempting to vandalize, then, unless you saw a bunch of rejections in a row.

Comment: As far as I know, if someone consistently gets their suggested edits rejected, they get blocked from the queue automatically anyway.

Comment: @lunboks I think that is a temporary 7 day lockout from editing, though.  It's not long term.  I don't think we should put users that perhaps miss a few items in a post and get an edit rejected in the same boat as those who are malicious.

Comment: @jonsca At the bottom of any suggested edit link is the "Editor Stats" which tells you about the latest bunch of suggested edits from that particular editor. In this scenario, for example, you can notice that the user in question *tried again*, though the links used were different for the second round.