# Repeated vandalism attempts

Tags: support, rejected-edits, vandalism

These two users seem to be fighting each other by defacing each others' posts with gibberish -

https://stackoverflow.com/users/1699283/patel-the-rock?tab=activity#patel-the-rock?tab=activity&sort=suggestions

https://stackoverflow.com/users/1505866/user7388?tab=activity#user7388?tab=activity&sort=suggestions

I'm running out of flags here, but I trust others to reject these edits. It does make me wonder though - why don't repeated edits getting rejected as vandalism (by multiple reviewers), merit some temporary blocking of edit privileges?

I saw lots of similar questions on meta (e.g. [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109266/does-the-rejection-of-a-suggested-edit-with-the-reason-vandalism-flag-the-post)) but they either treat anonymous edits or single attempts. In this case, the users are known (one of them has >600 rep), and we're talking about repeated attempts

Comment: I have given them both time outs. And repeated rejections do block editing for a bit, iirc.

Comment: @AndrewBarber - They were talking in Hindi language (written in English). And were using some offensive words as well.

Comment: @hims Yup. It was a back and forth started over disgareement over tags edits. Silly.

Comment: @hims056, interesting, google translate insisted that it's Astonian :)

Comment: Estonian, you mean? Sometimes Translate can't figure out a different language when it's not using its native character set.

Comment: Oops, yes, sorry (google translate shows the language name in my local language)

Comment: @hims056 - They are not just offensive words. They were literally swearing at each other with the *HIGH LEVEL* swear words of Hindi Language. Can't believe people get so childish over such petty things. And the saddest part being that they both have been members for over an year and 2 months.

Comment: @R.J [This seems relevant ;)](http://xkcd.com/386/)

Comment: @TheFestivusUnicorn - Seems like those fellas haven't looked back at all after getting that little time-out from you ;) And yeah, when there is someone wrong on the internet(specially when against you), you just cannot control your emotions :P